# Display message on success does not work

Tags: javascript

I have a simple wishlist script written in Javascript that adds an item into a wishlist. The script adds the item successfully into the user's list but I can't seem to display a success message.

I'm using the code below to try and display the success message. The script initially worked then just suddenly stopped working.

```
function AddItem(ToDoItem) {
    if ((ToDoItem != null) && (ToDoItem != "undefined" )) {
        NumToDoItems++;
        SetCookie('PT_ToDoItem'+NumToDoItems, ToDoItem, exp);
        SetCookie('PT_NumToDoList',NumToDoItems, exp);
        $(window).humanMsg('Added '+ToDoItem+' to Wishlist');
    }
}
```

Can you please have a look at the code and provide me some advice?

More info:

My html:

```
<div class="add-to-wishlist">
<a href="javascript:AddItem('<?php print htmlentities($title, ENT_QUOTES); ?>')">
<img class="add-to-wishlist" src="/images/add-to-wishlist-button.gif" border="0" /></a>
</div>
```

Here is the humanMsg. plugin for jQuery

```
(function($, window){

$.fn.humanMsg = function( message, options ) {
    return this.each(function(){
        var container = this == window || this == document ? document.body : this;
        !$.data(container, 'humanMsg') && $.data(container, 'humanMsg', new     $.humanMsg (container, message, options) );
    });
};

$.humanMsg = function( container, message, options ) {
    if (typeof message == 'object') {
    options = message;
    message = null;
}

var s = $.extend({}, $.humanMsg.defaults, options);

var $m,
    sizeContainer = container == document.body ? window : container;

$m = $('<div class="humanized-message '+s.addClass+'"/>')
.html(message || s.message)
.click(remove)
.appendTo(container);

$m.css({
    display: 'none',
    visibility: 'visible',
    top: ($(sizeContainer).height()-$m.innerHeight())/2,
    left: ($(sizeContainer).width()-$m.innerWidth())/2
})
.fadeIn(s.speed);

s.autoHide && setTimeout(remove, s.autoHide);   

function remove() {
    $m.fadeOut(s.speed, function(){
        $m.remove();
        $.removeData(container, 'humanMsg');
    });
}

};

$.humanMsg.defaults = {
message: 'no message was set',
autoHide: 3000,
addClass: '',
speed: 300
};

})(jQuery, this);
```

Looking into the error console I have this:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Property '$' of object [object Window] is not a function 
(anonymous function)
closing script tag manually
```

Comment: Hard to tell, you have a number of functions a global variable out of context.

Comment: `humanMsg` method/function lies where in your code? Can you post it here?

Comment: I have edited my op with more information. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error indicates that jQuery hasn't been included in the script.

Comment: No it did not fix the problem.

Comment: I'm sorry but what exactly do I have to change here? Also it displays an error on the console. Please refer to my op for the error.